How can I pass identifiers with my teams app manifest (for knowing that a specific user installed the app)
I created a teams app (bot) with the teams developer portal.
Im going to pass it to some organizations as a manifest.zip
I want to correlate the installation of the bot with the organization that Installed it aka I want to pass some identifier that I would get when a user adds the bot to a team. I haven't found a option to add metadata in the teams app manifest to do so. Is it possible?
(I know that I get the tenant ID and the relevant team ID) but I don't want to ask the organization for those beforehand, I want to pass some Id that I will link to them at my backend
I tried passing the ID in the valid domains field but I dont get those when the bot is added to a team

You cannot add metadata in the Teams app manifest. This is by design behaviour.
To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in
Teams Feedback Portal
.
